# In-line Styles not rendering properly after state change in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to apply a simple state change to a button in React.

```
'use strict';
class ReactButton extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {hovering: false};
  }

  onClick() {
    this.props.handleClick(this.props.text);
  }

  onHover() {
    this.setState({
        hovering: !this.state.hovering
    });
  }

  render() {
    const color = this.state.hovering ? 'blue' : 'default';
    const text = this.state.hovering ? 'Hover Text' : this.props.text;
    console.log(color, text);
    return (
        <button
            onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}
            style={{color: color}}
            onMouseEnter={this.onHover.bind(this)}
            onMouseOut={this.onHover.bind(this)}>
                {text}
        </button>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <ReactButton 
    text={"Original Text"}
    handleClick={(e) => console.log('clicked')} />,
  document.querySelector('#container')
);
```

If you [take a look at the demo](https://jsfiddle.net/n2fn3h3z/2/) you will notice that the text color changes to blue when the button is hovered, however when the mouse leaves the button the text color remains blue. The event is fired and the state does change triggering a re-render as evidenced by the text changing.

Why is react not updating the in-line style? What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`color:`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html) does not have `default` option,

change `default` to `inherit` (or default color name what you want like `#000000`),

```
const color = this.state.hovering ? 'blue' : 'inherit';
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/n2fn3h3z/3/)

[`Example-2`](https://jsfiddle.net/n2fn3h3z/4/)